# Menu getActive() returns "Trying to get property of non-object" in Search Component

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, templates, search

To identify the pages am using the following code

```
if($menu->getActive()->id == 203){} // some actions
```

this line returns error in search page. Search url goes like this

```
http://localhost/joomla/component/search/?searchword=destination&searchphrase=all&Itemid=103
```

when the page loads the following error occurs "Trying to get property of non-object".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because the $menu->getActive() is not returning an object, and here is because there is no menu item used for the search page.

To get rid of the php notice you are seeing, you could first check if the $menu->getActive() is an object and if yes then get its id property.

like so:

```
if ( is_object( $menu->getActive() ) ) { 
 //... 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you could use `JInput` to get the `ItemId`.

Try using the following:

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$ItemId = $jinput->get('Itemid', '', 'INT');

if ($ItemId == 203)
{
    // Something here
}
```

Comment: that's a cool solution as well